# Python Seaborn: Differential formatting of axis labels possible?

Tags: python, formatting, label, heatmap, seaborn

I am a Master student in molecular biology and want to plot a heat map displaying some promoter activity. Therefore I used the seaborn package of python. Things are working fine, but devil's in the detail: When it comes to labels, there are certain formation criteria I have to fulfill: 
My y axis is labelled like "P_ECF20-0922". The general pattern is that every label starts with a P (for promoter) and then something that specifies it. I'd like to have the P 'normal' and the specifics to be italic and of a smaller font size.

Is it possible to format my labels this way?
The only solutions I found so far affect the complete label text. Am I missing something obvious? I am thankful for any ideas.

My code looks like this:

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns

    # Dummy Data
    dummy_df = pandas.DataFrame(1.152, index=["P_ECF01"], columns=["RpoE1"])

    heatmap = sns.heatmap(dummy_df)
    heatmap.set_yticklabels(heatmap.get_yticklabels(), rotation=0)
    for label in heatmap.get_yticklabels():
        # Here it sets all italic. 
        label.set_style("italic")

    plt.show()
```

What I get looks like this: https://gyazo.com/0bdba68825f6b5e916da9f2d32a51585

Where I want my y axis formatting to be like: https://gyazo.com/3b846fa5c6cab4d6307764a9d56fc682 Here, the "P" is not formatted, but "ECF01" is smaller and italic.

Best wishes,
Christian

Comment: It's probably possible. Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you. I editied my post to include code and pictures.

Comment: Have you tried using LaTeX for your labels? For example, something like "P$_{\textit{ECF}}$"?